# ERROR: Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am using Noda Time (Date and Time Api) for my date conversions from UTC to a provided timezone.

Below is a method that returns a localized DateTime object based on the specified noda time zone id.

"utcDateTime" is the DateTime to convert and "timeZoneId" is the id of the time zone

```
    public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeFromUtc(DateTime utcDateTime, string timeZoneId)
    {
        utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        var timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timeZoneId];
        var convertedDateTime = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDateTime)
              .InZone(timeZone)
              .ToDateTimeUnspecified();

        return convertedDateTime;
    }
```

I get a date which is in utc from a collection and trying to convert it to the provided time zone but i get this error

> Ticks must be between DateTime.MinValue.Ticks and DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks.

```
DateUtility.ConvertDateTimeFromUtc(collection.Select(c => c.date).DefaultIfEmpty(DateTime.MinValue).First(), time_zone)
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete [mcve] we could try? It's hard to reason about this without knowing the values involved

Comment: You don't actually like DateTime.MinValue as a DefaultIfEmpty.  Which, when converted to local time, can become negative in the wrong half of the world.  You could just simply detect it in your conversion method.